# What am I doing wrong in this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am having a school assignment about Regex. I will explain it first.

I have to write a regex for checking URLs, the conditions I have to check are:

- Is the URL http(s) or ftp(s)?
- Is the domain .nl or .edu?
- There's atleast a third level domain, but if the domain starts with
  www. there has to be a fourth level domain.

Here is the regex I currently have:

```
(https?|ftps?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.(nl|edu)$
```

My URL is:

```
http://www.lib.hva.nl
```

The URL currently passes the regex, but when I remove .lib or .hva for example it still passes and that should not happen. When there's www. in the domain the domain should have four levels. Could someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: this is because of backtracking `[a-z]+` matches `www` and `(www\.)?` nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `[a-z]+` also matches `www`. In order to prevent this, use a negative look-ahead assertion before your first instance of `[a-z]+`, like this:

```
(https?|ftps?):\/\/(www\.)?(?!www\.)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.(nl|edu)$
```

Comment: Note that this will fail, if for whatever reason the url starts with `www.www.`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be failing that situation for me. Can you explain further?

Comment: Ah, I see now. That makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fine!

Answer (score 10):

this can be resolve using possessive quantifier `+` after `(www\.)?`

```
(https?|ftps?):\/\/(www\.)?+[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.(nl|edu)$
```

explanation

```
(https?|ftps?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.(nl|edu)$
```

matches

```
http://www.lib.nl
```

because after failing engine backtrack until `(www\.)?` and as `[a-z]+.` matches also `www.` the match succeeds, to avoid backtracking `(www\.)?`, possesive quantifier can be used.

other options can be to use a negative lookahead or an atomic group (as in the regex101 link).

[can be checked on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EIclXH/1/)

Comment: And a useful reference about quantifiers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: This is a very concise solution! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use {n} for exactly n occurences which might be more readable sometimes. You can easly increase subdomains amount.

`(https?|ftps?):\/\/(www\.)?+([a-z]+\.){2}(nl|edu)$`

Comment: Thank you! Very nice addon to make it shorter