# Capture stream of digits which is not followed by certain digits

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I wanted to capture a stream of digits which are not followed by certain digits. For example

`input = abcdef lookbehind 123456.....  asjdnasdh lookbehind 789432`

I want to capture 789432 and not 123 **using negative lookahead only**.

I tried `(?<=lookbehind )([\d])+(?!456)` but it captures `123456` and `789432`.

Using `(?<=lookbehind )([\d])+?(?!456)` captures only `1` and `7`.

Grouping is not an option for me as my use case doesn't allow me to do it.

Is there any way I can capture `789432` and not `123` using pure regex?
An explanation for the answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a possessive quantifier with a negative lookbehind

```
(?<=lookbehind )\d++(?<!456)
                  ^^ ^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RyHxY8/1).

A synonymous pattern with an atomic group:

```
(?<=lookbehind )(?>\d+)(?<!456)
```

**Details**

- `(?<=lookbehind )` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location in string that is immediately preceded with `lookbehind`
- `\d++` - 1+ digits matched possessively, allowing no backtracking into the pattern (the engine cannot retry matching from any digit matched with `\d++`)
- `(?<!456)` - a negative lookbehind check that fails the  match if the last 3 digits matched with `\d++` are `456`.

> Why lookbehind and why not lookahead

The negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` makes sure that a certain pattern does not match immediately to the left of the current location. A negative lookahead `(?!...)` fails the match if its pattern matches immediately to the right of the current location. "Fail" here means that the regex engine abandons the current way of matching a string, and if there are quantified patterns before the lookbehind/lookahead the engine might *backtrack* into those patterns to try and match a string differently. Note that here, a possessive quantifier makes it impossible for the engine to perform the lookbehind check for `456` multiple times, it is only executed once all the digits are grabbed with `\d++`.

You `(?<=lookbehind )([\d])+(?!456)` regex matches `123456` because the `\d+` matches these digits in a greedy way (all at once) and `(?!456)` checks for `456` after them, and since there are no `456` there, the match is returned.  The `(?<=lookbehind )([\d])+?(?!456)` matches only one digit because `\d+?` matches in a lazy way, 1 digit is matched and then the loolahead check is performed. Since there is no `456` after `1`, `1` is returned.

> why `++` possessive quantifier

It does not allow a regex engine to retry matching a string differently if there are quantified patterns before. So, [`(?<=lookbehind )\d+(?<!456)`](https://regex101.com/r/Dpg8GR/1) matches `12345` in `123456` as there is no `456` before `6`.

Comment: Could you please explain how/why this works? Why `lookbehind` and why not `lookahead`?. And why `++( possessive quantifier )`?

Comment: @ArunGowda I think I have just explained all that. See https://www.regular-expressions.info for more details on the constructs.

Comment: Sure thing :) . I was still going through your explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a negative lookbehind as well:

```
(?<=lookbehind )\d+\b(?<!456)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lzzB6/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=lookbehind )`: Positive lookbehind to assert that we have `"lookbehind "` before current position
- `\d+\b`: Match 1+ digits followed by word boundary
- `(?<!456)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have `456` before current position

---

**Alternative solution** using a negative lookahead:

```
(?<=lookbehind )(?!\d*456)\d+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0lzzB6/2)

We need `\d*` in lookahead expression `(?!\d*456)` so that we can skip `456` after matching 0 or more digits from current position.